# Laravel socket.io broadcast to everyone except the sender

Tags: redis, socket.io, laravel-5.1

I'm developing Laravel app with calendar events.

I'm using socket.io to broadcast the events (as per lesson here: https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1#)

my socket.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
    // 
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {

    console.log('Message Received! ' + message);

    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on *:3000');
});
```

It works fine but when the event is created it is pushed back to the sender and is duplicated.

I tried to use

```
socket.broadcast.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
```

instead of

```
io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
```

but the socket is not defined.

Is there a way I can do this without sending sender ID with event and then manually checking for it in the frontend?

Comment: I don't understand how is the event duplicated. You are receiving message from Redis and you are sending it with socket.io.
Is client sending data to other server (which you didn't provide) which is publishing to Redis? And your server is subscribing from Redis and emiting with socket.io back to clients?

Comment: @galethil the appointment is created in the calendar view (we use DayPilot here) and then it's data is sent via ajax to Laravel. Laravel creates it in the database triggers the created event which is broadcasted via redis and to all who have calendar view open (including the sender) when the message is received DayPilot adds the appointment to the view. So in this case in the senders view it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution, but you need to be able to send sender ID to Laravel (when creating calendar entry) and then publish it to Redis.
Also all clients have to send their IDs to socket.io server.

On your socket.io server you have to create some sort of login and database of clients. E.g.:

```
var clients = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  //receive login event with login data {senderId:'YourSenderID'}
  socket.on('login', function(data){
    //save socket ID
    clients[data.senderId] = socket.id;
  });
});
```

After that you are able to broadcast

```
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  console.log('Message Received! ' + message);

  message = JSON.parse(message);

  //you need to have senderId here, then you can broadcast for every socket except the socket of calendar entry sender
  io.sockets.connected[clients[message.senderId]].broadcast.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked, with an addition of: `io.sockets.connected[clients[message.senderId]]`